# Error: Set property > System.Windows.Data.MultiBinding.Converter' threw an exception

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have spent few hours to double check what's the error cause but I have no idea..

The error is

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: 'Set property
>   'System.Windows.Data.MultiBinding.Converter' threw an exception.' Line
>   number '363' and line position '86'.

XAML

```
<Grid Margin="1"
      DockPanel.Dock="Top">
  <Canvas x:Name="MinimapGrid"
          LayoutUpdated="MinimapGrid_LayoutUpdated">
    <Canvas.Resources>
      <local:OverlayRectangleRegionConverter x:Key="OverlayRectangleRegionConverter" />
    </Canvas.Resources>
    <Canvas.Background>
      <VisualBrush>
        <VisualBrush.Visual>
          <ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Wells, IsAsync=True}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
              <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding Rows, FallbackValue=16}"
                             Columns="{Binding Columns, FallbackValue=24}" />
              </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource WellTypeColorConverter}}"
                           Height="10"
                           Width="10"
                           Stroke="Black" />
              </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          </ItemsControl>
        </VisualBrush.Visual>
      </VisualBrush>
    </Canvas.Background>
    <Image x:Name="image"
           Height="410"
           Width="592"
           Source="Desert.jpg"
           Stretch="UniformToFill" />
    <Rectangle Fill="#FD9D5C5C"
               Canvas.Left="0"
               Canvas.Top="0"
               Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=image}"
               Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=image}"
               x:Name="rect">
      <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        <DrawingBrush Stretch="None">
          <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#99ffffff">
              <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Exclude">
                  <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                    <RectangleGeometry>
                      <RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource OverlayRectangleRegionConverter}">
                          <Binding Path="(Canvas.Left)"
                                   ElementName="image" />
                          <Binding Path="(Canvas.Top)"
                                   ElementName="image" />
                          <Binding Path="Width"
                                   ElementName="rect" />
                          <Binding Path="Height"
                                   ElementName="rect" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                      </RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                    </RectangleGeometry>
                  </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                  <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                    <RectangleGeometry>
                      <RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource OverlayRectangleRegionConverter}">
                          <Binding Path="(Canvas.Left)"
                                   ElementName="PART_ZoomThumb" />
                          <Binding Path="(Canvas.Top)"
                                   ElementName="PART_ZoomThumb" />
                          <Binding Path="Width"
                                   ElementName="PART_ZoomThumb" />
                          <Binding Path="Height"
                                   ElementName="PART_ZoomThumb" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                      </RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                    </RectangleGeometry>
                  </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                </CombinedGeometry>
              </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
            </GeometryDrawing>
          </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        </DrawingBrush>
      </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
    </Rectangle>
    <Thumb x:Name="PART_ZoomThumb"
           Canvas.Left="0"
           Canvas.Top="0"
           DragCompleted="PART_ZoomThumb_DragCompleted"
           DragDelta="PART_ZoomThumb_DragDelta"
           Cursor="SizeAll">
      <Thumb.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Thumb">
          <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                <Rectangle StrokeThickness="3"
                           Stroke="Red"
                           Fill="Transparent" />
              </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </Style>
      </Thumb.Style>
    </Thumb>
  </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

OverlayRectangleRegionConverter.cs

```
public class OverlayRectangleRegionConverter : MarkupExtension, IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values == null || values.Length != 4) return new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
        for (var i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            if (double.IsNaN((double)values[i]))
                values[i] = 0.0;
        return new Rect((double)values[0], (double)values[1], (double)values[2], (double)values[3]);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return new RectConverter();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you inherit from MarkupExtension?

Comment: to override the ProvideValue

Comment: But If you intend to use it just as converter you have no need for this inheritance at all. Just implement the IMultiValueConverter interface. Check, what happens in that case.

Comment: Thanks man! I just remove the inheritance and the override ProvideValue and everything works nice. The error happens is due to return new RectConverter() which the class doesn't exist. The problem solved :)

Comment: Just a note on ProvideValue. For value converters, you usually inherit from markup-extension to ease the way you use converters. You do not have to create it as a explicit resource and can use it in the binding directly: {Binding Path=Something, Converter={OverlayRectangleRegionConverter}}.